# Precompiling handlebars template with custom helpers

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, helper, precompiled-templates

I have a `message.handlebars` template which works perfect when compiling it in the browser.

I precompiled it with `handlebars -message.handlebars -f -message.js` successfuly.

Then in my ASP.NET MVC site I'm adding the references as:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/handlebars.runtime-v1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/handlebars-helpers.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/templates/message.js"></script>
```

The `handlebars-helpers.js` contains some custom helpers used by the message template.

I took this approach from this guy's [comment](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars/issues/8#issuecomment-11580455), but it's not working. I'm getting an error when doing `var html = Handlebars.templates.message(data);`. Again this works perfectly when compiling it in the browser, so it's not a problem of context.

The error I'm getting is:
[image]

Is this the correct approach to precompile and use custom helpers? Or is there a way to include those helpers in the precompiled template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the version of handlebars on the server. NPM installs the latest by default and the version 2 alpha was causing the issue. Found this fix on Github (https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/734):

```
npm uninstall handlebars -g
npm install handlebars@1.3 -g
```

Everything working!